# best choice for stating that you've seen a new word in a text

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I've always had this problem phrasing this sentence.

what can I put in this gap?

**'' when I was reading an article, I .... this new phrase/word which I don't know the meaning**''

> when I was reading a text,
>
> - I faced this new phrase/word
> - I came across this new phrase/word
> - I ran into this phrase/word

or maybe there is a better way of asking that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary defines face as meaning   **Confront and deal with or accept**. It is usually used about a difficult situation. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/face

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of saying this is

> When I was reading an article, I **saw** this phrase/word

which is a statement of fact and has no connotation for difficulty of understanding which would need to be added context.

your other alternatives "came across" and "ran into"  work also

> When I was reading an article, I **came across** this phrase.
>   When I was reading this article, I **ran into** this word.

"Ran into" would have the implied meaning of "difficulty in understanding".

> I **ran into** this word which I didn't understand.

Using "faced" would not be correct eventhough you were "facing" the article.

Comment: the verb ''face'' mostly followed by problems? I mean does it have a specific connotation?

Comment: Yes, "faced" can be used when talking about a problem but then the context is usually mentioned also "I faced a problem when...", "I faced great difficulty when..." meaning you came "face-to-face" with *something*, "faced" by itself, it does not necessarily mean "there is a problem" as in "I **faced** north while walking."

Comment: An alternative to _saw_ would be _stumbled across_, which likewise states a mere fact and makes no connotation about difficultly.

Answer (score 1):

Both "came across" and "ran into" are fine.

The idiom you might want in your first example is "*came face-to-face with*", but this is a metaphor usually applied to meeting a *person*, so using it for an *object* is figurative and not always appropriate.

> While shopping at the market I came face-to-face with my old flame from high school, and I was so surprised I couldn't think of anything to say.

Comment: Yes, to come across, run across, find